# How to check sense hat screen on|off using node.js

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, node-red

I am working in raspberry pi using sense-hat . Now i am using sense hat simulator in node-red. Now I have to check what is the status of sense-hat screen. How can I do this?

I have tried by using:

`msg.payload.screen=="on"`

and

`msg.screen=="on"`

but didnt work. can any one please help me?

I have also tried:
`msg.background=="off|on"` and `msg.device=="off|on"`

Comment: What do you mean "status of the sensehat screen"? that any LED is non-black?

Comment: @techhunter the sidebar info tells you everything the node allows you to do. I don't know where you've got `screen` from, but it's not something this node does.

Comment: The command sent to the device should :have a command id/type of ‘display’
be formatted as a JSON object
have a single property called ‘screen’ with a value of either ‘on’ or ‘off’.
For example: {"screen":"on"} or {"screen" : "off"}

Comment: @knolleary I want to check whether sense-hat received {screen:on} |{screen:off} command.

Comment: @techhunter ah, you are doing the Into to IoT coursera course. The task is to send a command from Node-RED on Bluemix, over WatsonIoT to your raspberry Pi running Node-RED. Your flow on the Pi should receive that command and convert it to the appropriate command to send to the attached SenseHAT. You do not send {screen:on} to the SenseHAT itself. Please follow up on the Coursera assignment forum.

Comment: @knolleary Thanks for your helpful response. yep, msg.payload.screen=="on" was right but after receiving command from bluemix.

Answer (score 1):

Not at all sure what you are actually trying to do, but this should help.

The SenseHat frame buffer is an 8x8 matrix of LEDs. That means there are 64 LED's and you write a 16-bit RGB565 value to each address in `/dev/fb1` to make the LED come on a certain colour. 64 LEDs at 2 bytes each makes 128 bytes.

So, to turn off all the LEDs, you can send a bunch (128 bytes) of zeroes:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/fb1 bs=128 count=1
```

And to turn on the first few LEDs with random colours:

```
echo AnyJunk > /dev/fb1
```

So, if you want to check all the LEDs are off, you need to compare the 128 bytes in the framebuffer to zero. You can do that by generating 128 bytes of zeroes and then running `cmp` like this:

```
cmp <(cat /dev/fb1) <(dd if=/dev/zero bs=128 count=1)
```

So, for an example:

```
echo AnyJunk > /dev/fb1      # Turn some LEDs on

# Check all zero, but they are not so the comparison fails
cmp <(cat /dev/fb1) <(dd if=/dev/zero bs=128 count=1)
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
128 bytes (128 B) copied, 0.000237917 s, 538 kB/s
/dev/fd/63 /dev/fd/62 differ: byte 1, line 1

echo $?
1
```

Turn all LEDs off and check again:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/fb1 bs=128 count=1

cmp <(cat /dev/fb1) <(dd if=/dev/zero bs=128 count=1)
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
128 bytes (128 B) copied, 0.000289063 s, 443 kB/s

echo $?
0
```

Keywords: Raspberry Pi, RPi, SenseHat, Sense Hat, framebuffer, /dev/fb, RGB565, LED, matrix, commandline, command-line

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your code. But it looks like python code in linux platform.  I upvote your answer because it will be helpful for others who search for above.